# Do we need to call dev.off() after creating a pdf file?

Tags: r

When I call dev.off() my pdf gets created but I get the following message "null device 1".
I don't get any warning when I remove dev.off and my pdf gets created so why do I need to call dev.off for?

```
plot(x # independent variable (population_density)
, y # dependent variable (case_fatality_rate)
, main = "ScatterPlot - Case Fatality Rate vs Population Density Per Square Mile" # chart 
title
 , xlab = "Population Density Per Square Mile" # x-axis label
, ylab = "Case Fatality Rate" # y-axis label
, pch = 19 # point shape (filled circle)
, frame = T # surround chart with a frame
, xlim = c(0, 1200), ylim = c(0, 3)
)
model <- lm(y ~ x, data = dataset) # compute the linear model
abline(model, col = "blue") # draw the model as a blue line

hist(y # depandant variable (case_fatality_rate)
, main = "Histogram - Case Fatality Rate Frequency" # chart title
, xlab = "Case Fatality Rate",
ylab = "Frequency",
col = "#f0ffff",
breaks = 15,
freq = FALSE,
prob = TRUE,
xlim = c(0.5,2.5),
ylim = c(0.0,2.0)
)

lines(density(y, adjust=1.2),  col="blue", lwd=2) 

grid(nx = NA, ny = NULL,
 lty = 1, col = "gray", lwd = 1)

dev.off()
```

Comment: typically yes, the pdf device will remain active and you will keep writing to it until you close the device. you can also have multiple open at once but only one will be written to at a time until you close the current device or switch. you should not be able to open your pdf without closing

Comment: So why do I get  "null device 1" when I try to close it?

Comment: that is just a message telling you which device is now active after you closed one, it is the same as `dev.cur()`